# Ruby On Rails & bootstrap_form - dropdown in f.text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, dropdown

**I want to have dropdown at text_field in Ruby on Rails form.**
I wrote the code like that:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: "dropdown-toggle", data: {toggle:"dropdown"} %>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      # some dropdown items
  </ul>
</div>
```

My code doesn't work and I get an error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
```

**In my investigation, the problem seems ....**

```
<div class="dropdown"
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="text">
  </div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    # some dropdown items
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since I'm using bootstrap form, `f.text_field` is automatically wrapped by "form-group".
I don't need this wrapper in order to make dropdown work well.

So, the following code will work, but I don't know how to realize it by using f.text_field in bootstrap form.

```
<div class="dropdown"
  <input class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="text">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    # some dropdown items
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to coexist "f.text_field", "form-group", and bootstrap dropdown.

Comment: What do you mean bootstrap form, are you using some gem for it?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I use the gem "bootstrap_form". (the usage is `bootstrap_form_with` in place of `form_with`)

Comment: So the gem has a helper for select (a dropdown) , why are you not using it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to dropdown with text_field (just like suggestion), so I don't use `f.select`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at offical document (https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap_form)

You may want to define your own form group div around a field. To do so, add the option wrapper: false to the input field. For example:

```
f.form_group :user do
  f.email_field :email, wrapper: false
end
```